# What does "feeling proud with" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've found in a Facebook post:

> Feeling proud with NNN at someplace

I'm not sure about this "**feeling proud with**" and what it could mean?

I tried asking at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313133/what-does-feeling-proud-with-mean) but it was closed as off-topic.

Comment: It's probably an overly-shortened (and not particularly idiomatic, imho) was of saying something like *I'm at [someplace], and I'm feeling proud because NNN is with me* (i.e. - speaker thinks very highly of NNN, and assumes others will think the same and thus look up to her for being in such elevated company).

Answer (score 3):

That sentence doesn't really make sense on its own. On Facebook, you can add certain tags to your post, and it writes those as a sentence: *Feeling [x]* to show an emotion. *with [person/people]* tags one or more people in your status. And *at [someplace]* tags a location. And then Facebook renders it as in your example: *Feeling [x] with [person/people] at [someplace].*

The word *proud* here is most likely related to the following definition of *pride*, [from Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pride), and not one of the more negative ones.

> a feeling of happiness that you get when you or someone you know does something good, difficult, etc.

What the person is proud *of* is not clearly stated in that sentence alone. It's most likely either something else mentioned in the status, or the person tagged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hazarding a guess that, in your example, **NNN** is a triple net lease and the person posting may be an investor (lessor).

The reason someone would feel proud to have an NNN for a particular investment is because only the highest creditworthy tenants can get such a deal, where the tenant is responsible for taxes, insurance, and maintenance, thereby having some significant advantages flow to the owners/investors.  The tenant may get back a certain discount in the base rent as an advantage.

The owner can take pride in the fact that the property in their portfolio is good enough to attract a significant tenant who can afford a triple net lease which should help him to sleep at night, actually for many nights to come.

It would be the same as saying

> Feeling proud **with** my new Ferrari.

Having ownership of something valuable.