# Proud of or proud with?

Tags: prepositions

Please tell me if the following sentence is correct.

> You should be proud with your achievements.

Should I use "of" or "with"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "feeling proud with" mean?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84237/what-does-feeling-proud-with-mean)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I am not convinced by your possible duplicate. That question is about text that is automatically generated by Facebook and, not surprisingly, it's grammatical but not natural. None of its answers address the **of** issue, which would be the correct answer for this question.

Comment: @JavaLatte: My position here is that although in general we use ***proud of*** rather than ***proud with***, this is essentially a matter of idiomatic preference, not "grammatical rules" as such (as you yourself say, *it's grammatical but not natural*). And although the top answer on the linked question doesn't explicitly say much about the "preposition of choice", it does at least highlight the fact that it's switching the OP's  cited ***with*** to ***of*** by putting the substitution in italics. If more needs to be added, I think it should be there, not here on a separate question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the prepositions are not exactly interchangeable.  I would never  in a million years say: proud with my achievements. It sounds ghastly and completely non-idiomatic. And I don't care who generated it. In English, people are proud of their achievements. Here is idiomatic use of proud with: He stands proud with his father in front of his decorated brother's grave. That yes. But the meaning is completely different! My goodness.

Comment: To be proud with a thing means: to be proud wearing, showing or displaying it. To be proud OF a person or status has a different meaning.

Comment: @Lambie: If it's good enough for Shakespeare, it's good enough for me:
 *His heart like an agate with your print impressed, / **Proud with his form,** in his eye pride expressed* [(Love's Labour's Lost)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ULR7QAgmvaQC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22proud+with+his+form%22&source=bl&ots=_LKyP_l5Dv&sig=MEGzpXYWEDRqiowErh-ki5_UC_Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF7s345rDUAhVLIcAKHQjrDE0Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22proud%20with%20his%20form%22&f=false). I think you consistently conflate "most common form" with "**only** grammatically acceptable form".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Shakespearean usage is not modern English usage. Nothing like confusing people even more, is there?

Answer (score 4):

As written, it's *proud of*. If you add a comma after *proud*, use *with*.

- *You should be proud of your achievements*. This is an exhortation to take pride in what they have achieved.
- *You should be proud, with your achievements*. This is an exhortation to take pride (in themselves). The achievements are cited as supporting reasons for them to do so.

Answer (score 2):

"Proud of", always.  I can't think of any case, even a non-standard one, where "proud with" would be correct, though of course it would always be understood!

"Proud about" would be one informal alternative: "[She is/You should be] very proud about [her/your] achievements".  "Proud of" would still be more common, but "proud about" doesn't sound as strange as "proud with".

"[Very/Exceptionally] [happy/satisfied]  would be, I think, the closest "with" alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure "correct" is really a relevant concept here. There are hundreds of written instances of [*feel / feeling / felt proud **with** (something engendering pride)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22feel+proud+with%22), and no-one has taken issue with [*Feeling proud with my new Ferrari*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/84246/126) as presented in an answer to the question I've cited as a duplicate. But I agree that *idiomatically* we're very unlikely to use ***with*** rather than ***of*** where the main verb is *I **am** proud [preposition] [object of pride]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It's pretty clear from context that the OP is trying to create a single clause.  I read "feeling proud with my new Ferrari" as being 2 clauses "I'm feeling proud, with my new F." in which the pride is general and diffuse, affected by possession of the F. but not solely determined by it.

Comment: I agree, but there's no real clear-cut distinction between the two contexts. I have no problem with, say, [I was as proud as punch with my dad before I thought about it for a second,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+proud+as+punch+with%22) In fact, I think ***with*** is actually *better* than ***of*** in that context, even though clearly it references "object **causing** pride" rather than "person/thing in proximity **while experiencing** pride".

Comment: If you feel proud with a thing, you are personifying the thing. It means: When I do x with it, when I am riding in it, I feel proud. I feel proud about my new Ferrari. I feel proud WITH MY FATHER when we march in military parades. I agree with MMacD. Now, I feel proud with my new flag shirt=it means when wearing it. Proud with, when used, is a completely different meaning than proud of or about. And it is easy to misuse proud "with".